# calculate the length of the split lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cogo

I want to split lines in my shapefile so i am using COGO tool to split lines. After splitting I want the length of these new split lines in the attribute table.
I have checked in many places but couldn't find anything regarding this topic.

so is there anyone who knows how to calculate the length of all the split lines and then store all of them in the attribute table.

Comment: Why do you have tagged `python` and `python-script-tool`? Are you using COGO from python script or from `arctoolbox`?

Comment: sorry that was by mistake

Answer (score 2):

In the Attribute Table view, if you right-click a column, you will see Calculate Geometry, Length is an option.

Also, if you put your data into a file geodatabase, ArcGIS will automatically add a column Shape_length for you. Just another benefit of using a File Geodatabase.